# javascript shadowing of variable throw an exception

Tags: javascript

The code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict'; // es6 is on
  var a = {
    b: 3
  };
  (function() {
    var a = a.b + 4;
    console.log(a);
    /** many lines where a is used */
  })()
})()
```

I am expecting to get 7 in console, but I got an exception. I can understand why this happaned, and work-around will be tupically rename internal variable. But I'd like to avoid this, so is there another way to force this working without renaming variables? I am working in es6-compatible env, so might be in es6 there is something for such cases?

Comment: why do you have to use same variable name?

Comment: @Venugopal, in the original code I replace object with one of nested classes object, keeping original interface/usage, but a bit differ functionality , just for this scope.

Answer (score 3):

`var a` reserves the local variable name even before any of the function body is executed; it shadows it immediately, not only upon assignment. Imagine it executing like this:

```
var a = undefined;
a = a.b + 4;
```

As such, there's no way to get the parent scope's value of `a` without renaming the inner variable.

---

To work around this, you can pass **the value** into your IIFE:

```
var a = { b: 3 };
(function (_a) {
    var a = _a.b + 4;
    console.log(a);
})(a)
```

Or even use the fact that a function parameter already declares a new local variable name:

```
(function (a) {
    a = a.b + 4;
    console.log(a);
})(a)
```

Comment: unfortunatelly this is not working, as far af I have event0listeners there, not a IIFE, so I cannot pass _any_ params there, as far as closure parameters controlled by event emmiter

Comment: @msangel You can still create an IIFE around an event listener that captures `a`

Answer (score 1):

First proposed varian not working for me as far as I have event-listeners there, not a IIFE, so I cannot pass any params, as far as closure parameters controlled by event emmiter.
But the implementation suggested me another solution, whitch is fit perfect:

```
(function(){
'use strict'; // es6 is on
var a = {b:3};
function getA(){
    return a;
}
(function(){
    var a = getA().b+4;
    console.log(a);
    /** many lines where a is used */
})()
})()
```

Answer (score -1):

u override 'a' by defining ( local version "var a")... just say a = a.b+4; since you did define it, it wont become new global variable and will use the other...
also you are overriding object a with primitive 7 value, so in this self called method it's nothing, but in another place where you want to call it again, there won't be any object, and theres only a primitive left to you

Comment: I do not care about future of the variable, I use same variable for displaying.

Comment: BTW you are still overriding it, the time you say var a... it mean the a you are pointing to, is not the a you defined before, you should just use `a = a.b+4` instead of `var a = a.b+4`

Comment: if I would use  `a = a.b+4`, then I wold override `a` globally, but I need to do this only in closure scope

Comment: you said it your self... that you don't care. if you override it, you no longer have it. if you define a local with same name, you access that one instead. do something like this: `a.temp = a.b+4`, then here you defined a variable on the fly, and you can later check,
 `if (a.temp != undefined) {//do something}` or `if (a.temp == undefined){//do something}`
The rules defined by people who create languages, is that you always access to the most local variable, so if you use a in many place, you got what is closer to you. you can also try this: `b = a.b+4` then `var a = b` i'm not sure if it work

Comment: in that way, you defined var a after reading what you require. i'm not sure if the js interpreter detect that `var` but it's worse giving a try... but still these two `a` are different object. so later you call a again, it again depend on what is closer to you.